# Jquery Window load

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding some div on window scrolling, which is wokring fine. but it keeps showing div  when i am doing scrolling. i want div will not show untill first will not execute completely. Can anybody tell me what kind of changes shall i made more

Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        classname = 'hide_class_' + j;

        jQuery('.hide_class_' + j).before("<div class='roatingimage' style='text-align:center; height:35px;'><img src='ajax-loader.gif'></div>");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.roatingimage').hide();
            jQuery('.hide_class_' + j).fadeIn();
            j = j + 1;
        }, 5000);

    }
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, can you please provide jsfiddle code, for all the work that you have done so far.

Comment: try with   }, j*5000);

Comment: it will delay more on each window.scroll.  i just want not to execute window.scroll until previous window.scroll will not complete

Comment: what do you mean by "complete". can you provide the exact issue that you are having and what is the preferred behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, with a scroll Flag:

```
var scrollEnable = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
                if(scrollEnable && $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    scrollEnable = false;
                    classname='hide_class_'+j;

                    jQuery('.hide_class_'+j).before("<div class='roatingimage' style='text-align:center; height:35px;'><img src='ajax-loader.gif'></div>");
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                    $('.roatingimage').hide(); 
                            jQuery('.hide_class_'+j).fadeIn();
                            j=j+1;
                            scrollEnable = true;
                        }, 5000);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: what is benefit to declare a variable here

Comment: it is keep a track whether the current scroll is in processing or not. When the current scroll completes it can enable scrolling again. This can also be achieved by turning the event `off` too.